# AppRegistryNotReady in Django 1.7 and Python 3.4 when using Multiprocessing

Tags: python, django, python-multiprocessing

In a Django view I spawn a thread (class of threading.Thread) which in turn creates a multiprocessing pool of 5 workers. 
Yes, I know using a task queue like Celery is usually the accepted way of doing things, but in this case we needed threads/multiprocessing.

Both the Thread and each of the Multiprocess Workers access items in the database. However, doing any call to a Django Model in the Thread or Worker causes a "django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet" exception.

Here is the full stack trace:

```python
Process SpawnPoolWorker-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 254, in _bootstrap
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\multiprocessing\process.py", line 93, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 108, in worker
    task = get()
  File "C:\Python34\lib\multiprocessing\queues.py", line 357, in get
    return ForkingPickler.loads(res)
  File "d:\bryan\Documents\Projects\spreadmodel_3.4_venv\lib\site-packages\djang
o\db\models\fields\__init__.py", line 59, in _load_field
    return apps.get_model(app_label, model_name)._meta.get_field_by_name(field_n
ame)[0]
  File "d:\bryan\Documents\Projects\spreadmodel_3.4_venv\lib\site-packages\djang
o\apps\registry.py", line 199, in get_model
    self.check_models_ready()
  File "d:\bryan\Documents\Projects\spreadmodel_3.4_venv\lib\site-packages\djang
o\apps\registry.py", line 131, in check_models_ready
    raise AppRegistryNotReady("Models aren't loaded yet.")
django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Models aren't loaded yet.
```

It is odd to me that I don't see any part of my code in the stack trace.

I've tried doing django.setup() in the Thread init and at the beginning of the method the Workers start, still with no success.

At no point in my models do I try to read anything from the database like the common issue of doing a foreign key to the user model.

---

EDIT:

I can get the database queries to work in the Thread by putting django.setup just under the Simulation class instead of having it in the init method.
But I'm still having issues with the queries in the Workers.

Edit2:

If I modify Python's queue.Queue file and put the django.setup() call in the get function, everything works great. 
However, this is not a valid solution. Any ideas?

Edit3:

If I run the tests inside PyCharm, then the test associated with this problem works. Running the test in the normal command line outside of PyCharm (or running the view server from a server [django test server or CherryPy]) results in the above error.

---

If it helps, here is a link to the views.py on GitHub.

https://github.com/NAVADMC/SpreadModel/blob/b4bbbcf7020a3e4df0d021942ddcc5039234bd88/Results/views.py

For future reference (after we fix the bug), you can see the odd behaviour on commit b4bbbcf7 (linked above).

Comment: I figured out how to get the Threads working. You need to setup django in the class, not in the init.

Comment: Modifying pythons queue.Queue's get function to setup django gets the job done. However, this is a bad fix. Ideas?

Comment: I am quite surprised that any `django.setup()` would be needed in any thread, I've never used it and I've always been able to evaluate my querysets within them.

Comment: Were you on Django 1.7? Because I've never had this problem in Django versions prior to this. In fact, the exact code for this project works great in 1.6; however, we were looking forward to some features in 1.7 and started doing the upgrade this week when we ran into the problem. It is related to the new fangled AppRegistry...

Comment: So running the test code in PyCharm results in a success. However, running the code outside of PyCharm still gives the above result with the Process Workers. What is PyCharm doing to the test environment that allows the Workers to have the Django environment setup already?